# the header() is not redirecting me to another page

Tags: php, redirect, header

In the below code i am trying to redirect the page after the values are written into database. but after once the data is written the page is not getting redirected

the code is

```
IMPORT EMPLOYEE DETAILS
        </h2>
        <br><br>
        <form method="post" action="import.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <!--  <input type="text" name="excelname"> -->
          Please Choose your excel(in .xls format):  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="multifile">
           DATE: <input type="date" name="period" id="date" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="IMPORT" name="submit" class="button">&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </form>
<?php
if($_POST["period"])
{
$Date=$_POST["period"];



  $sql1="INSERT INTO report (report_date) VALUES ('$Date') ";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);

}
$Date=NULL;
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "excel/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$upload_name='excel/'.$name;


echo'<br>';

    if($name != null)
    {
    $excel->read($upload_name);
    $x=1;
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
      echo "\t<tr>\n";
      $y=1;
      $index=0;
      $arr = array();
      while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
        $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
        //echo "\t\t<td>$cell</td>\n";
        if($x>1)
        {
         $arr[$index]=$cell;

          $index++;
        }
        $y++;

      }

    if(!empty($arr))
     {

if(!empty($n1))

{

 $n1=null;
        }
 else {

    $sql="INSERT INTO emp_csv (search_parameters,empty,report_type,operation,web_rep_no,test_performed_by,sales_person,region,customer,distributor,report_group,test_date,date,part,operation_type,material_designation,material_group,conditions,comments,savings,number_1,number_2,approved_report,flag,cases,tool_body,main_insert,grade,manufacturer,d,vc,n,f_fz,l,ap,ae,coolant,mach_power_reqt,edge,performance,cost,saving_per_annum,hardness,type_of_cut,flank_wear,finish,primary_failure_mode,chip_shape,reason_for_index,r_id) VALUES ('$arr[0]','$arr[1]','$arr[2]','$arr[3]','$arr[4]','$arr[5]','$arr[6]','$arr[7]','$arr[8]','$arr[9]','$arr[10]','$arr[11]','$arr[12]','$arr[13]','$arr[14]','$arr[15]','$arr[16]','$arr[17]','$arr[18]','$arr[19]','$arr[20]','$arr[21]','$arr[22]','$arr[23]','$arr[24]','$arr[25]','$arr[26]','$arr[27]','$arr[28]','$arr[29]','$arr[30]','$arr[31]','$arr[32]','$arr[33]','$arr[34]','$arr[35]','$arr[36]','$arr[37]','$arr[38]','$arr[39]','$arr[40]','$arr[41]','$arr[42]','$arr[43]','$arr[44]','$arr[45]','$arr[46]','$arr[47]','$arr[48]',(SELECT MAX( report_id ) FROM report))";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close();
     }
 echo "\t</tr>\n";
      $x++; 
            } 
             header('Location: http://localhost/kmtcrg/confirm.php');
    } 
    } 
    ?>
```

can anyone help me i am not getting whats going wrong in this

Comment: are you getting any error. because looking at your code its look like your headers are already sent and then you are trying to redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you need to buffer at very beginning of code using `ob_start` [read about ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

and also move your php code at top as panther suggested. so your code will look more like this

```
<?php
ob_start(); //using ob_start is a good practice 

// your code
header();

?>

Your HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Before header can't be any output.

Move PHP script above your HTML.

```
<?php

// your code
header();

?>

Your HTML
```